# Actionbar tab text (android:textAllCaps=false) is not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, android-actionbar-compat

I am using [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to style the action bar.

Basic parent Theme: `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`

I want to change the `action bar` tabs `text` to lower case (by default its Upper case).

I tried the following.

***XML Code:***

```
<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item></style>
```

***Java Code:***

```
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    


    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) 
    {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));

    }


    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
        {
        }
    });
```

But it's not working.

Kindly help me to overcome this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check whether it is defined  as you want in string.xml

Comment: @KaranMer. I have given the string in Java file..

Comment: private String[] tabs = { "Android", "Windows", "Blackbery", "Iphone"};